# iOS 13 - diacritic in large title causes jumping of content and warning UITableViewAlertForLayoutOutsideViewHierarchy

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, ios13

Problem starts when self.navigationItem.title contains one from these characters: ľťýíúá

The same time the title is set (in viewDidLoad) the warning UITableViewAlertForLayoutOutsideViewHierarchy is thrown (see the screenshot of the system methods queue). Subsequently the navigation controller starts behave incorrectly: when I pop to the root VC then the view of LargeTitle and view of root VC have overlap (6px). As bonus - using swipe gesture to navigate back the view of root VC jumps after the pop animation is finished.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

you can avoid that warning by checking if the tableview is on Window...

```
extension UIView {

   var isOnWindow: Bool {
      return window != nil
   }
}
```

then you can...

```
if tableView.isOnWindow {
   /// set the title here
}
```

and defer setting the title when this is true.

Comment: Yes, thanks for help. This is exactly what I tried after publishing this post and I found out that this warning didn't was the source of the overlay problem. 

The overlay (bad large title animation / placement) occurs even after removing this warning. And I noticed that native iOS apps (e.g. Settings app) have also problem with characters with diacritic in title text.

Comment: ....
I have Slovak localization in my phone and after visiting any screen in Settings app that has diacritic (úáíýľť...) the large title anymation is broken. I reported it to Apple month ago but without any outcome.